# Query the list of CITY names from STATION that do not start with vowels. Your result cannot contain duplicates

Tags: sql, mysql

> error details :SQL0104N An unexpected token "NOT" was found following
> "m station WHERE  CITY". Expected tokens may include:
> "<interval_qualifier>". 
> SQLSTATE=42601

Tried in Hacker rank

```
command : select distinct city from station WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiouAEIOU].*$';
```

Tried the command Not worked
Doing from last 15 mins

Comment: This appears to not be a `MYSQL` error, it might be related to `DB2` ! please tag the correct RDBMS you are using

Comment: in MySQL it works just fine https://dbfiddle.uk/_IUdI_SR

Comment: Works fine on MySQL, https://dbfiddle.uk/O2BlzWXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `SQLSTATE=42601` error seems to indicate that your SQL engine is *Postgres*, not MySQL, the latter which does actually support `RLIKE`.  So, you should either change your SQL engine to MySQL or stick to Postgres and use regex:

```sql
select distinct city
from station
where CITY !~* '^[aeiou].*$';
```

On DB2, use:

```
select distinct city
from station
where not regexp_like(CITY, '^[aeiou].*$', 'i');
```

Comment: It seems the OP is likely using `DB2` https://dbfiddle.uk/QMRhYrFx